# How to include header file dynamically through constructor for dynamic content in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

> Hi, I am stuck on a problem where i have to echo dynamic meta
>   description and meta keywords for a specific page. I have included the
>   header file into the constructor and it contains a code that has
>   language change option through session.
>
> I have a table named contents which contains content of the pages and
>   also 2 columns (metakeywords,metadescription). I want them to
>   dynamically display on each page where i get the id of the page.
>
> Below is the code so far : please help

**This is controller :**

```
public function __construct(){
$this->load->model('home_m');
$data['query'] = $this->home_m->seo($id);
$this->load->view('site/include/head', $data);
$header = $this->header();
$this->load->view('site/include/header', $header);
}

public function header(){        
        $site_setting = $this->home_m->getRow('general',array('gen_id' => 1));
        $data['site_setting'] = $site_setting;
        $header_links="select * from ".PRE_FIX."header_links";
        $data['header_links'] = $this->home_m->getCustomRecords($header_links);
$this->set_language();
if ( $site_setting->language == 1){
            $language = "english";
        } else {
            $language = "french";
        }

        if ( $this->session->userdata("setLanguage") != ""   ) {
            $language = $this->session->userdata("setLanguage");
        }
        $data['language'] = $language;
         return $data;
    }
```

Now for eg: i want to display the header metakeywords and meta description on the following page which is webhosting.

```
public function webhosting(){
$this->set_language();
$language =  $this->session->userdata("setLanguage");
$get_plans = "Select * from gdn_planstesting where page='webhosting'";
$data['get_plans'] = $this->home_m->getCustomRecords($get_plans);
$this->load->view('site/webhosting', $data);
$this->load->view('site/include/footer',$data);
}
```

**This is model :**

```
public function getCustomRecords($customQuery)
    {
        $recordSet = $this->db->query($customQuery);
        return $recordSet->result();
    }

function seo($id){
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM gdn_planstesting WHERE planstestingid='$id'");
return $query->result_array();
    }
```

**This is view :**

```
foreach($get_plans as $pl) {
    $pid = $pl->planstestingid;
    $pname = $pl->planname;
    $planStatus=$pl->plan_status;
}

foreach($query as $value){
echo $query->id;
}
**This is the header file :**

    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/front/css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/front/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/front/css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title>Your title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container-fluid headertop">
            <!-- <div class="container-fluid"> -->
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
    <?php
        if($language == "english"){

            $lang1 = "class='active'";
            $lang2 = "";
        } else {

            $lang1 = "";
            $lang2 = "class='active'";
        }?>
            </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem with the code you posted? As it stands, your 'site/include/header' file will be loaded every time your controller is called. Is that not what you are expecting?

Comment: I have added the header file code too in the post. The header will always load when ever the controller is called but only with static content. for eg: if im openning index.php page then i should get data from database table named index which contains metakeywords,metadescription columns, if i open the page webhosting, it should display metakeywords,metadescription from the webhosting table .

Comment: What is the structure/contents of the table `gdn_planstesting`? What do you expect `$id` to be?

Comment: Now the issue is : i have a few tables for eg: planstesting,contents,pages .. all three tables contains 2 similar columns, i.e meta_keywords,meta_description. I just want to display these two columns data dynamically whenever the page is called. contents table has content_id,content_title,content_description etc and planstesting table has planstesting_id,planstesting_page,planstesting_data. etc

Answer (score 2):

I finally Solved the issue by doing the following code:
Although its not dynamic but fulfills my requirements. Thankyou @dnapierata for your help. i couldnt have done it without your help trust me.

```
public function header(){    

    $ur = $this->uri->segment(1);
   // echo $ur;

        $site_setting = $this->home_m->getRow('general',array('gen_id' => 1));
        $data['site_setting'] = $site_setting;
        $header_links="select * from ".PRE_FIX."header_links";
        $data['header_links'] = $this->home_m->getCustomRecords($header_links);



        $this->set_language();

        if ( $site_setting->language == 1){
            $language = "english";
        } else {
            $language = "french";
        }

        if ( $this->session->userdata("setLanguage") != ""   ) {
            $language = $this->session->userdata("setLanguage");
        }

        $data['language'] = $language;




       if($ur != 'resellerhosting' || $ur != 'businesshosting' || $ur != 'webhosting' || $ur != 'domain' || $ur != 'aboutus' || $ur != 'contactus'){

        $this->set_language();


        $language =  $this->session->userdata("setLanguage");

//echo "select * from ".PRE_FIX."content where page_name='$ur' and content_language = '".$language."'";

        $ss="select * from ".PRE_FIX."content where page_name='$ur' and content_language = '".$language."'";
        $data['ss'] = $this->home_m->getCustomRecords($ss);

}

if($ur == 'resellerhosting' || $ur == 'businesshosting' || $ur == 'webhosting' || $ur == 'domain' || $ur == 'aboutus' || $ur == 'contactus' || $ur == ''){



//echo "select * from ".PRE_FIX."planstesting where page='$ur'";

        $sd="select * from ".PRE_FIX."planstesting where page='$ur'";
        $data['sk'] = $this->home_m->getCustomRecords($sd);

}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it and you're welcome! Upvotes are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your `header` method in your **controller** you must first make a call to your **model** which should query your database for the meta information that you need.

**Controller:**

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->load->model('home_m');
    $header = $this->header();
    $this->load->view('site/include/header', $header);
}

public function header(){        
    $site_setting = $this->home_m->getRow('general',array('gen_id' => 1));
    $data['site_setting'] = $site_setting;
    $header_links="select * from ".PRE_FIX."header_links";
    $data['header_links'] = $this->home_m->getCustomRecords($header_links);
    $this->set_language();
    if ( $site_setting->language == 1){
        $language = "english";
    } else {
        $language = "french";
    }

    if ( $this->session->userdata("setLanguage") != "" ) {
        $language = $this->session->userdata("setLanguage");
    }
    $data['language'] = $language;

    //Get the meta information from the model
    $data['meta'] = $this->home_m->seo($this->uri->segment(1), $this->input->get($id));

    return $data;
}
```

`$this->router->method` simply returns the method that was called for this controller, we can use this to determine which table to select from.

**Model:**

```
public function getCustomRecords($customQuery){
    $recordSet = $this->db->query($customQuery);
    return $recordSet->result();
}

function seo($table, $id){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $table"."_id='$id'");
    return $query->row();
}
```

Once you have the information, then you can output it in your `sites/include/header` view.

**Header View:**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $meta->metadescription; ?>" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $meta->metakeywords; ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/front/css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/front/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/front/css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title>Your title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container-fluid headertop">
            <!-- <div class="container-fluid"> -->
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
    <?php
        if($language == "english"){

            $lang1 = "class='active'";
            $lang2 = "";
        } else {

            $lang1 = "";
            $lang2 = "class='active'";
        }?>
            </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
```

Comment: So far i have done this but im getting Message: 
Undefined variable: id 

below is the code for controller: 

`$data['query'] = $this->home_m->seo($id);
 $this->load->view('site/include/head', $data);` 

  below is the code for model method : 

`function seo($id){

      $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM gdn_planstesting WHERE planstestingid='$id'");
 return $query->result_array();
    }`

Comment: Please update your post with the new controller and model methods. As it looks, you will probably need to create a method in your model to get meta information from the database.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the mvc files. One thing I'm still missing is how you are getting a paticular page's `$id`. In my example I just looked at `$this->input->get('id')` but this may not be correct.